# Add summary row in Gridview for one column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have this `GridView`, and I want to add in the footer summation of PremiseScore score (third column).

How I can do this?

```
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PremiseUno" HeaderText='<%$ Resources:Language, grdPremiseUno %>' ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PremiseUno"  >
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gHeaderStyle" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gControlStyle" />
                        </asp:BoundField>

                         <asp:BoundField DataField="PremiseName" HeaderText='<%$ Resources:Language, grdPremisesName %>'
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="grdPremisesName" >
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gHeaderStyle" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gControlStyle" />
                        </asp:BoundField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PremiseScore" HeaderText='<%$ Resources:Language, grdPremiseScore %>' ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PremiseScore"  >
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gHeaderStyle" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gControlStyle" />
                        </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText= '<%$ Resources:Language, btnDelete %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PremiseUno") %>'  onclick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



            </Columns>
```

Comment: There is a tutorial on how to implement this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310552.aspx. Are you using C# or VB.NET? You basically have to implement the RowDataBound event and keep a running total of the PremiseScore column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the bound field to a template field, you can access the control holding the value of premise score:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="test">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="testLabel" Text='<%# Eval("PremiseScore") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>               
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can then do the following to compute the sum in the Databound-event of the gridview:

```
protected void Grid_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow footerRow = grid.FooterRow;
    var sum = (from GridViewRow row in grid.Rows select ((Label)row.FindControl("testLabel")).Text).Sum(d => Convert.ToInt16(d));

    footerRow.Cells[0].Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

I assume here that all values are ints, but it´s easily convertible to other value types.